# All AJAX "POST" requests are getting sent as "GET" requests in Android Play Store Cordova App

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am having a very strange issue with my Cordova app. In iOS (both on development and in production) all AJAX calls work fine. When installing the Android app by just downloading the APK file and installing that way, all AJAX requests work fine.

But when using my app from the Google Play Store distribution, all AJAX "POST" requests are being sent as "GET" requests, which as you can imagine is breaking functionality.

I have a hot fix on the backend right now which accepts only the important 'POST's as 'GET's, but this is obviously not ideal.

Has anyone ever ran into this problem before or have any ideas on how to fix this?

UPDATE: Now the "GET" method works, but none of my AJAX parameters are being sent to the backend from the request (again, only when installing from Google Play Store).

Comment: I remember once I ran into something similar.  You are sending the method in all caps right?  "post" != "POST".  Maybe that may be the issue?

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I am! I thought about that too.

Comment: `installing the Android app by just downloading the APK file`. Where are you downloading it from? And who is installing it?

Comment: Which api are you using to send the data? (i.e. pure ajax or with a library like jquery)

Comment: are you using https? in case it's https, are you using a trusted certificate?

Comment: @jcesarmobile this is exactly what the problem was!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I was not using a properly certified SSL certificate over an https connection!